# I need a function whose integral ratio for f(2x)/f(x) remains stable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

This is a very difficult problem to describe, but in essence its very simple, so I'll make an example. If we take the function

$f(x)=x$

its integral (as function of how far we want to take the integral) is

$g(a)=\int_{0}^{a} x \,dx= \frac{a^2}{2} $

now we want to test the following:

**If we take the ratio of g(2x)/g(x), will it be the same ratio for every x?**

so basically:

$\frac{g(2x)}{g(x)}=\frac{\frac{(2a)^2}{2}}{\frac{a^2}{2}}=\frac{(2a)^2}{a^2}=\frac{4*a^2}{a2}=4$

Which means no matter what x we plug into $g(2x)/g(x)$, it will be 4. But what if I want to replace $f(x)=x$ with another function, for a specific value of g(2x)/g(x), like for example 3? I've tried using $f(x)=bx$, but no matter which b I plug in, it will always be 4 (because of the square cube law). And if I use some other formula $g(2x)/g(x)$ will become unstable (different ratios for different x), So heres my question, what is the simplest formula I could use instead of $f(x)=x$ that would remain stable and would allow me to change $g(2x)/g(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider a function of the form

$$f(x)=x^b,\, b \neq -1.$$

This gives

$$g(x)=\frac{x^{b+1}}{b+1}$$

and

$$\frac{g(2x)}{g(x)}=\frac{2^{b+1}x^{b+1}}{b+1}/\frac{x^{b+1}}{b+1}=2^{b+1}.$$

That means you have to choose $b=\log_2 r -1$ to get a desired ratio $r=\frac{g(2x)}{g(x)}$.

This gives you a solution for any positive $r$, for $r=4$ you get $b=1$, as your own example shows.

Now, $f(x)=x^b$ will generally not be defined for non-positive $x$ if $b$ is not an integer. If this is a problem for you, you can simply define $f(-x) = f(x)\; \forall x \ge 0$ to get  function that is defined on all the real numbers.

$r=0$ is obviously impossible.

For negative $r$ I'm not sure if such a function can be found.